# Android M "Runtime Permissions" not requested at runtime?

Tags: android, permissions

I was getting ready for runtime permissions on android M when I recently figured out that (at least on theGgalaxy S6 of my friend), still all permissions have to be confirmed at installation time (Google Play).
He has Android M, and sure you can revoke the permissions in the app settings now, but initially when you start the app after install, everything is granted.

I am kind of surprised, that's not the "Runtime Permissions" I was expecting.

Any hints on that? Did I miss something?

Comment: And if you target api 23 and dont request permission you will get a permission exception on android 6.0 devices if you try to use a dangerous permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> This lesson describes how you implement permissions requests on apps that target API level 23 or higher, and are running on a device that's running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher. If the device or the app's targetSdkVersion is 22 or lower, the
>   system prompts the user to grant all dangerous permissions when they
>   install or update the app.

The runtime permissions will only take effect if you update the target SDK to 23